# How to make label comparison case insensitive in XCUITest?

Tags: xcuitest

At work, we have a couple of tests that rely on labels. Sadly the label is case sensitive so "Attachment" is different from "attachment". Is there a way to configure XCUI to do label comparison case insensitive?

I'm hoping for something like [continueAfterFailure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html) exist.

I tried looking online and in stackoverflow ([uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxcuitest%5D%20uppercase), [lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxcuitest%5D%20lowercase), [case](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxcuitest%5D%20case) and [case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxcuitest%5D%20case%20sensitive)) but nothing useful came out. I know the best solution is to create AX ids and will also work towards that, but I was wondering if doing case insensitive label comparison was possible.

Any pointer is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can form an [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate) to do case insensitive string matching e.g.

```swift
extension XCUIElementQuery {
    func caseInsensitiveLabel(_ label: String) -> XCUIElement {
        return self.matching(NSPredicate(format: "label MATCHES[cd] %@", label)).firstMatch
    }
}

let app = XCUIApplication()
let label = app.staticTexts.caseInsensitiveLabel("sOmE tExT")
XCAssert(label.exists)
```

Comment: That's what we ended up using:

`let labelPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS[c] '\(partialLabelOrID)'")
 let identifierPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier CONTAINS[c] '\(partialLabelOrID)'")
 let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(
    orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [identifierPredicate, labelPredicate])`